# Can someone explain me this boolean algebra equation

Tags: boolean, operators, algebra

Can someone explain me this boolean algebra equation, using the table method and telling me explanation?

```
    xy->z
```

I know the boolean logical operator "->", but what does xy mean? Is this only x, only y, or is it a mistake in the following equation?

[image]

Comment: to me it seems like: x and y => z

Comment: I cannot upload the image, but here is the link, to see with more details: ht tp:/ /prikachi. com/images/44/7397044F. png just delete the spaces. I know the other operators, but x and y together? is this (x and y)?

Comment: Yes I confirm that it seems an implicit dot (logic multiplication = and operator) to me, like those dots: http://www.tpub.com/neets/book13/NF130220.GIF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xy is the logical AND of x and y. In your notation the 'v' symbol is used as logical OR. Usually '+' is used as OR as well.

Thus the left side of your equation reads "(x and y) or ([not x] implies [y and z])"

Comment: Thanks kayson! That is the answer I needed. I am familiar with the V symbol, I just didnt knew that xy = x and y. Thanks !